# symfony createForm dynamic parameters error

Tags: php, class, symfony, parameters

I'm encountering a strange problem when calling create form method in symfony 5.1.

The code failing :

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Documents\ventehabitation;
use App\Form\Documents\ventehabitationType;
use App\Entity\UserDocuments;
use App\Entity\Documents\contratdetravail;
use App\Form\Documents\contratdetravailType;
```

```
public function fillDocument(DocumentsRepository $docRepo, Request $request, int $id)
    {
            $currentDoc = $docRepo->findBy(["id" => $id]);
            $name = $currentDoc[0]->getDocModelName();
            $docEntity= str_replace("_", "", $name);
            $formEntity = $docEntity."Type::class";
            $docEntity = "App\\Entity\\Documents\\".$docEntity;

            $document = new $docEntity();

            $form = $this->createForm($formEntity, $document, [], "");
```

Error : Could not load type "ventehabitationType::class": class does not exist.

Same error if I prepend "App\Form\Documents\" to the $formEntity variable.
But working fine If I explicly write ventehabitationType::class in createForm parameters, which isn't helping me in this case since I need to initiate dynamically my forms.

composer.json infos in case you would need it :

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "App\\Controller\\Documents\\": "src/Controller/Documents/",
            "App\\Entity\\Documents\\": "src/Entity/Documents/",
            "App\\Form\\Documents\\": "src/Form/Documents"
        }
    },
```

My class does exist. For example ventehabitationType form class is created in "App\Form\Documents\" and contains :

```
namespace App\Form\Documents;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use App\Entity\Documents\ventehabitation;

class ventehabitationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('test', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'test',
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ventehabitation::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My entity is loaded correctly, only the first parameter of createForm is the problem.

This seems to be such a noobie problem but still I can't figure it out...
Maybe it is a PHP restriction ?

If someone can solve the problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The [`::class`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) keyword will return a string with the fully qualified class name according to its namespace. However, it's a compile time operation so you cannoy use it at runtime.

Since it returns just a string and that's all the `FormFactory` expects, you can build it in the same manner as your `$docEntity` class name:

```
$formEntity = 'App\Form\Documents\\'.$docEntity.'Type';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved it.

I didn't know this was a compile time operation, though it seemed obvious once I read your comment. 
Thanks again !

Comment: @ww0k Well, it's a keyword after all, so if you embed it in a string it won't be evaluated. Glad it's working.